# Multiple AND Condition - ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I have a scenario with single or multiple records exist for people depending on their class enrollment. Some people are enrolled in multiple terms or just a single term.  They can take more than one class in the term they are enrolled in.

I am trying to return only the people that are enrolled in multiple terms(H5A, H5B), which would have multiple records and they are only taking 1 course in each term.

The following condition is not working, returns no results where I know they exist.  My Where clause is not correct.  Please advise.

```
    where 
  (a.PART_OF_TERM = 'H5A' and a.COURSE_COUNT = 1) 
    and 
      (a.PART_OF_TERM = 'H5B' and a.COURSE_COUNT = 1)
```

Thanks, Gordon, for the response.

I have included the entire qry with your suggestions.
I believe I am pulling the right amount of people at this point who have 1 course enrollment in each session/term (H5A, H5B).

Question:  If I include a.part_of_term in the outer group by and select, I will receive zero results.  Is this because the HAVING clause is an aggregate function and will not work if each part_of_term is returned?  Thank you

```
  select 
  a.TERM_CODE, 
 -- a.PART_OF_TERM, 
  a.PIDM,
  a.COURSE_COUNT
    
from
(
select  
  SSBSECT.SSBSECT_TERM_CODE Term_Code,
  SSBSECT.SSBSECT_PTRM_CODE Part_of_Term, 
  SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_PIDM PIDM, 
   count(SSBSECT.SSBSECT_CRN) Course_Count
  
from 
  SATURN.SCBCRSE
  inner join SATURN.SSBSECT
    on (SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE = SSBSECT.SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE
    and SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB = SSBSECT.SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB)
  left join SATURN.SSRXLST 
    on (SSBSECT.SSBSECT_TERM_CODE = SSRXLST.SSRXLST_TERM_CODE
    and SSBSECT.SSBSECT_CRN = SSRXLST.SSRXLST_CRN)
  left join SATURN.SFRSTCR
    on (SSBSECT.SSBSECT_TERM_CODE = SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE
    and SSBSECT.SSBSECT_CRN = SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_CRN
    and SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE in ('RE', 'RW'))
  
  
 where 
      SSBSECT.SSBSECT_TERM_CODE = '202102'
      and SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_COLL_CODE = 'SU'
      and SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM =
        (select max(scbcrse_eff_term) from saturn.scbcrse xppd
        where
        xppd.scbcrse_subj_code = scbcrse.scbcrse_subj_code
        and
        xppd.scbcrse_crse_numb = scbcrse.scbcrse_crse_numb and xppd.scbcrse_eff_term <= ssbsect_term_code)
       and SSBSECT.SSBSECT_SSTS_CODE in ('A', 'E', 'O')
       and SSBSECT.SSBSECT_PTRM_CODE in ('H5A', 'H5B', 'HSL', 'H10', 'HND')
       and SSBSECT.SSBSECT_SEQ_NUMB <> '0'
      
group by 
    SSBSECT.SSBSECT_TERM_CODE, 
    SSBSECT.SSBSECT_PTRM_CODE,
    SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_PIDM
    
    
order by
    SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_PIDM, 
    SSBSECT.SSBSECT_PTRM_CODE
) a

where 
    a.COURSE_COUNT = 1
      and a.PART_OF_TERM in ('H5A', 'H5B')
group by 
   a.TERM_CODE, 
   --a.PART_OF_TERM, 
   a.PIDM,
   a.COURSE_COUNT
having 
   count(distinct a.PART_OF_TERM) = 2
        
order by
    a.PIDM;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also show the complete query.

Comment: May be you want `or`, not `and` between conditions? `where (a.PART_OF_TERM = 'H5A' and a.COURSE_COUNT = 1) or (a.PART_OF_TERM = 'H5B' and a.COURSE_COUNT = 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Your query is going to fail, because no row can have two different values for `PART_OF_TERM`.  Presumably, you want aggregation.  Something like:

```
select person
from t
where a.COURSE_COUNT = 1 and a.PART_OF_TERM in ('H5A', 'H5B')
group by person
having count(distinct PART_OF_TERM) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to generalize the answer ..

```sql
select person
from t
where COURSE_COUNT = 1 
group by person
having count(distinct PART_OF_TERM) >1
```